# Send Audio data represent as numpy array from python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, numpy, flask, html5-audio

I have a TTS (text-to-speech) system that produces audio in numpy-array form whose data type is `np.float32`. This system is running in the backend and I want to transfer the data from the backend to the frontend to be played when a certain event happens.

The obvious solution for this problem is to write the audio data on disk as a wav file and then pass the path to the frontend to be played. This worked fine, but I don't want to do that for administrative reasons. I just want to transfer only the audio data (numpy array) to the frontend.

What I have done till now is the following:

### backend

```py
text = "Hello"
wav, sr = tts_model.synthesize(text)
data = {"snd", wav.tolist()}
flask_response = app.response_class(response=flask.json.dumps(data),
                                    status=200,
                                    mimetype='application/json' )
# then return flask_response
```

### frontend

```js
// gets wav from backend
let arrayData = new Float32Array(wav);
let blob = new Blob([ arrayData ]);
let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let snd = new Audio(url);
snd.play()
```

That what I have done till now, but the JavaScript throws the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

This is the gist of what I'm trying to do. I'm so sorry, you can't repreduce the error as you don't have the TTS system, so this is an [audio file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kTW6HQFGaAcKG8OuXiO_-fkmny6XI5LJ) generated by it which you can use to see what I'm doing wrong.

### Other things I tried:

- Change the audio datatype to `np.int8`, `np.int16` to be casted in the JavaScript by `Int8Array()` and `int16Array()` respectively.
- tried different types when creating the `blob` such as `{"type": "application/text;charset=utf-8;"}` and `{"type": "audio/ogg; codecs=opus;"}`.

I have been struggling in this issue for so long, so any help is appriciated !!

Comment: from what I remember from tts, they send a base64 buf, have you tried to do so?

Comment: No, the data is returned in `numpy`, so do you know how to convert numpy to base64 buffer... I'll google that, but maybe you have a faster answer

Comment: I've tried it using `base64.b64encode(wav)`. On the frontend, I used `let snd = new Audio("data:base64," + path;);` and it didn't work. I tried `data:audio/ogg;base64," + path;` and `data:audio/wav;base64," + path;` and they didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample as is does not work out of the box. (Does not play)

However with:

- StarWars3.wav: OK. retrieved from [cs.uic.edu](https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/)
- your sample encoded in PCM16 instead of PCM32: OK (check the wav metadata)

Flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

with open("sample_16.wav", "rb") as binary_file:
    # Read the whole file at once
    data = binary_file.read()
    wav_file = base64.b64encode(data).decode('UTF-8')

@app.route('/wav')
def hello_world():
    data = {"snd": wav_file}
    res = app.response_class(response=json.dumps(data),
        status=200,
        mimetype='application/json')
    return res

@app.route('/')
def stat():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

js

```
  <audio controls></audio>
  <script>
    ;(async _ => {
      const res = await fetch('/wav')
      let {snd: b64buf} = await res.json()
      document.querySelector('audio').src="data:audio/wav;base64, "+b64buf;
    })()
  </script>
```

### Original Poster Edit

So, what I ended up doing before (using this solution) that solved my problem is to:

- First, change the datatype from `np.float32` to `np.int16`:

```
wav = (wav * np.iinfo(np.int16).max).astype(np.int16)
```

- Write the numpy array into a temporary wav file using `scipy.io.wavfile`:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
wavfile.write(".tmp.wav", sr, wav)
```

- Read the bytes from the tmp file:

```
# read the bytes
with open(".tmp.wav", "rb") as fin:
    wav = fin.read()
```

- Delete the temporary file

```
import os
os.remove(".tmp.wav")
```

Answer (score 3):

### Convert wav array of values to bytes

Right after synthesis you can convert numpy array of wav to byte object then encode via base64.

```python
import io
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

byte_io = io.BytesIO()
write(byte_io, sr, wav)
wav_bytes = byte_io.read()

audio_data = base64.b64encode(wav_bytes).decode('UTF-8')
```

This can be used directly to create html audio tag as source (with flask):

```jinja
<audio controls src="data:audio/wav;base64, {{ audio_data }}"></audio>
```

So, all you need is to convert `wav`, `sr` to `audio_data` representing raw `.wav` file. And use as parameter of `render_template` for your flask app. (Solution without sending)

Or if you send `audio_data`, in `.js` file where you accept response, use `audio_data` to construct url (would be placed as `src` attribute like in html):

```js
// get audio_data from response

let snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64, " + audio_data);
snd.play()
```

because:

> `Audio(url)` Return value:
> A new HTMLAudioElement object, configured to be used for playing back the audio from the file specified by url.The new object's preload property is set to auto and **its src property is set to the specified URL** or null if no URL is given. If a URL is specified, the browser begins to asynchronously load the media resource before returning the new object.